# Pre-installed movies and photos on new MBA

Tags: macbook-pro

MBA 13"

I when I got it home for the first time. I switched it on I checked how much disk space I had left. I was surprised to see 45MB of movies and photos 471MB.

I can't find the movies and the photos in the finder window. Where are they and what are they?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where did you see you had 471MB of photos ?

Comment: I went to 'about this mac" and on the storage it gives the details. However, I can't find them in the finder. I think they are just samples that I want to remove as its disk space I want to save. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made the following test :

```
 sudo find /system -name "*.png" | wc -l
```

returns 4553 on my mac : There are over 4000 images in my `/System/` directory. It's probably your case too.

Using

```
sudo find /system -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 du | awk '{total+=$1} END{print total}'
```

I get 248352K, that 250MB. Not your 450MB but we are getting close. You can assume the files you see are system files (yes your system uses images and video !)

I would definitely **not** suggest to delete theses files since they are used by the system.

Answer (score 1):

*(Not able to comment, since I don't have enough rep)*

My understanding is that they are tutorial pictures and videos from pre-installed apps such as keynote, iPhoto or Garageband.

You could use a image file reducer such as JPEGmini to reduce the file size of those images, but there's probably no need.